# Performance on PureComponent vs stateless functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the following React code:

```
class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { item: 'Test', };
  }

  render() {
    return <TodoItem item={this.state.item} />
  }
}


class TodoItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.item}</div>
  }
}


function TodoItem(props) {
  return <div>{props.item}</div>
}
```

Above there is a stateful parent component `Todos` and 2 versions of the same child component `TodoItem`. One of the versions is a pure component and the other is a stateless functional component.

I understand the performance benefits from using a PureComponent, but I am wondering if React 16 applies the same shallow comparison and performance benefits to a stateless functional component?

If not then why? It seems that by using either I am telling React my component has no state and therefore will only update if the parent component's state changes.

Comment: stateless components do not apply React rendering life-cycle. It doesn't have state, and always re-render when receives new props. So the answer is that stateless component always faster, unless you don't want to trigger the render function (eg: the component is outside window)

Comment: @FisNaN just to clarify are you saying the stateless functional component is faster than a PureComponent which only does a shallow compare on incoming props? Does the functionality component always re-render even if there's no difference because it maybe doesn't do a shallow comparison? Or does it now with React 16?

Comment: Please consider this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2zoq5pw4r0 Yes stateless component always updating when receive different props (even with same value). However because it doesn't have the comparison, it slightly faster. That's why input normally uses stateless. List item normally uses PureComponent.

Comment: @FisNaN I don't understand why a functional component would be faster if it triggers all of it's logic and rendering everytime with no need. Surely the shallow compare for PureComponent would be faster because it would not result in all of the functionality triggering, or a render?

Answer (score 5):

> I understand the performance benefits from using a PureComponent, but I am wondering if React 16 applies the same shallow comparison and performance benefits to a stateless functional component?

No, not yet. There were indications from the React team this will change in the future, but as of today, stateless functional components still behave like React.Component in regards to rerendering.

If you need to optimize for performance, stick with `React.PureComponent` or `React.Component` implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`. Keep in mind that if you're using redux and react-redux, `connect()` will try to handle the shallow compares for you as well on both functional and class-based components ([read up on in in the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/ImmutableData.md#how-does-react-redux-use-shallow-equality-checking)). You might also want to check out [recompose and its `onlyUpdateForKeys`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#onlyupdateforkeys) helper, for example.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me but I'm wondering why FisNan thinks a stateless functionality component would be quicker than a PureComponent. Also I follow Airbnb eslint config which says to use functions for stateless components...

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you call your pure component in JSX. When using mounting (as in your snippet) it don't get you a lot of optimization. @Dominik and folks in comments to question describe why. But [here](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) guy states that calling pure components as functions can result in 45% speed up.
`Todos` component will look like this:

```
class Todos extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { item: 'Test', };
  }

  render() {
    return TodoItem({ item: this.state.item });
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never thought of calling a functional component like this